CORS Issues in Microfrontends deployement with Vite and Module Federation
I was building a microfrontend application using reactJS with two main components:

A header application deployed on Netlify or any server
A main application that consumed the header as a remote module


import path from "path";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [
 react(),
 federation({
 name: "MainApp",
 filename: "mainApp.js",
 remotes: {
 header: "https://headerapp.netlify.app/assets/header.js",
 },
 shared: ["react", "react-router-dom"],
 }),
 ],
 build: {
 target: "esnext",
 minify: false,
 cssCodeSplit: false,
 },
 preview: {
 port: 3003,
 },
 resolve: {
 alias: {
 "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
 },
 },
});

This error prevented the main application from loading the remote header module, effectively breaking the microfrontend architecture.
After deploying the microfrontend repos to a live URL, Everything should be working perfectly as in the local development environment. However, we encounter this frustrating CORS error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://headerapp.netlify.app/assets/header.js. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.


All we needed to do is to add a server configuration option for disabling CORS to the main application’s vite.config.js file
export default defineConfig({
 // … other configurations
 server: {
 cors: false,
 },
});

Here’s the complete vite.config.js file for the main application with this change:

import path from "path";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: "MainApp",
      filename: "mainApp.js",
      remotes: {
        header: "https://headerapp.netlify.app/assets/header.js",
      },
      shared: ["react", "react-router-dom"],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 3003,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
  server: {
    cors: false,
  },
});


